# Why does ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent() increment the counter for an already present key?

Tags: java

Running this example code (from Cay Horstmann)

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,LongAdder> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (String key : "Row, row, row a boat".split("\\PL+"))
    counts.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new LongAdder()).increment();
System.out.println(counts);
```

The output is

```
{a=1, Row=1, row=2, boat=1}
```

I am surprised to see `row=2` because I expected computeIfAbsent() would increment only when it found the first "row" and not the second one.

Comment: What is your reasoning? The increment happens with the return value of `computeIfAbsent(..)`, not within the `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I thought the increment was part of the lambda passed to computeIfAbsent . I now see that it was not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`counts.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new LongAdder())`

This entire expression can go one of two ways:

1. `key` is already in the `counts` map. In this case, the 'computer' function (`k -> new LongAdder()`) is completely ignored; it isn't run at all. Instead, the value associated with that key is returned.
2. `key` is *not* in the `counts` map. In this case, the 'computer' function is executed once, and the value it returns is now associated with the key.

In other words, it's identical to:

```
LongAdder result;
if (counts.containsKey(key)) result = counts.get(key);
else {
  result = new LongAdder();
  counts.put(key, result);
}
return result;
```

Which is a mouthful, potentially less efficient, and potentially non-atomic whereas `.computerIfAbsent` can be atomic if you use the right implementation (such as `ConcurrentHashMap`).

Here's the clue: **You then invoke `.increment()` on this result, regardless of whether we're in the #1 case or the #2 case**.

In other words:

First 'row' is seen, `computeIfAbsent` ends up executing the lambda and thus, runs something like `counts.put(k, new LongAdder())` and **THEN** you call `.increment()` on this.

Next, the second 'row' is seen, `computeIfAbsent` ends up being equivalent to `counts.get(key)`, and you call `.increment()` on that. Which is the same LongAdder we made when we saw the first 'row', and thus this is the second time you are invoking `increment()` on it.

It's not `computeIfAbsent` that's incrementing anything. It's the `.increment()` that increments something.